# gitlab push failed when I migrate repository A to B

Tags: git, repository, gitlab

I want to move a full Git repository.
and I copy repository A file, delete old remote then add new remote, I push all my local branch to origin

[image]

this is error description, I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Are you trying to move something locally, or on the actual remote repository?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is by moving your repo to a new remote one, you are pushing the *full* history of that local repo.

And that includes commits *not* done by you, with a different email than yours.
The remote repo has a pre-receive hook which will block such a push.

You would need to contact the remote repo hosting service support in order to relax that hook temporarily and allow the push to proceed.